# ARC error: init methods must return a type related to the receiver type [4]

Tags: ios, initialization, automatic-ref-counting

Whats wrong with this code under ARC? I get above error:

```
- (Moment *)initMoment:(BOOL)insert {

if (insert) {
    self.moment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Moment" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  } else {
    self.moment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Moment" inManagedObjectContext:nil];
  }
return self.moment;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your goal here... your function should be `init`ing `Moment`, so it should set up a `Moment` and return `self`. What you are doing here is setting a `self.moment` property with the return value of adding something to a managed object model...

Comment: I use somebody else's code (probably should not do that). But I also tried "Moment *moment and "return moment;" I get the same compiler error.

Comment: Right, but typically an init is something in the form of `-(id)initWithInsert:(BOOL)insert { if (self = [super init]) { // setup } return self}` . When you `return moment` you are returning something that is not there.

Comment: That did it. Tnx. If you put it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Done... just so you know you could have done it as a class method, alloc/init in the method, and return the object.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was trying to fix the symptom. There are better ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `init` method that was posted in the question was in the wrong form. The `init` method should (usually) have the form:

```
-(id)initWithParams:(BOOL)aBoolParam {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //do stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem with code above was that it was done as a class method, so if the poster wanted to  do this he had to do `moment = [[Moment alloc] init]` and return it.